# HttpSession API

Tags: java, session, servlets

I'm new to servlets, I have question in HttpSession,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
       // processRequest(request, response);

        String name = request.getParameter("Name");
        String phone = request.getParameter("Phone");
        String dummy = "some";

        HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
        ses.setAttribute("SesName", name);
        ses.setAttribute("SesPhone", phone);
        ses.setAttribute("SesName", dummy);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("./SessionApiImp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }
```

now in another servlet,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
       // processRequest(request, response);
        HttpSession sess = request.getSession();

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        pw.println(sess.getAttribute("SesName"));
        pw.println(sess.getAttribute("SesPhone"));

    }
```

-So which values is assigned to this? I tried and it returned value associate with dummy. What is the reason?

Thanks,
Anil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the last value you set for the attribute `SesName` is `dummy`:

```
ses.setAttribute("SesName", name);
ses.setAttribute("SesPhone", phone);
ses.setAttribute("SesName", dummy); // HERE!
```

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> If an object of the same name is already bound to the session, the
>   object is replaced.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually pretty intuitive: if you put new value under existing key, it overwrites previous value. Otherwise it would not be possible to update already existing entry in session.

```
ses.setAttribute("SesName", name);
//...
ses.setAttribute("SesName", dummy);
```